# p-group of maximal class

Tags: finite-groups, p-groups

I am trying to prove that if $G$ is a $p$-group of maximal class and order $p^4$ ($p$ odd), then its unique two-step centraliser $G_1=C_G([G,G])$ is of the form $C_{p^2}\times C_p$. It is clear from Burnside's classification theorem that $G_1$ is not cyclic. How can I rule out the case $G_1$ is not elementary abelian. I checked in GAP this is true for the case $p=3$.

Comment: class means nilpotency class?

Comment: yes, nilpotency class 3.

Comment: it's a linear algebra exercise: what are elements of order $p$ in $GL_3$ over a field of characteristic $p$?... MathSE seems more appropriate.

Comment: the best I could conclude about the action of an element $s \in G \setminus G_1$ on $G_1$ as action on $GL_3({\mathbb F}_p)$ is that it has a nontrivial stabiliser. But $G$ has a nontrivial centre. It doesn't contradict anything.